# add an array to a multi-dimensional array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have been searching for a simple answer, but it just doesn't exist, or I don't know how to ask the right questions, to gain the right answers.

Here is the simple to understand question:
I have a big multi-dimensional array, as illustrated here::

```
$dataFile = array (
           array(
              array(
                data => 'infohere_01',
               )
            ),
          array(
                data => 'infohere_02',
               )
            ),
```

etc etc say up to infohere_125 and beyond...

I want to BREAK up the individual arrays creating a simple to manage .php files - using stupid logic ie KISS I thought this would do it. By using include, then stepping through all the seperate .php snippets to make a BIGGER array...

```
   <?php
       $dataFile = array (
                         include '/datafile_01.php';
                         include '/datafile_02.php';
                         );
    ?>
```

etc etc to include up to and above '/datafile_125.php';

with each include '/datafile_01.php';
being just::

```
<?php
    array(
       array(
             data => 'infohere_01',
            )
          ),
?>
```

Not the most elegant way to do it - as it doesn't work...

I cannot find a simple solution.  I find complex solutions that do not apply to a simple need.

Comment: It doesn’t work this way, you can not use `include` inside an array definition. You could define an empty array before the includes, and then append a value to the array in each include file – but to do that you will have to use the same variable name inside each include file.

Comment: @techouse Thank you for that stunningly useful contribution.

Comment: Appreciate include does not work within an array - double checked it in case it may, but the server returns an error report::
   syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /home/ja..

Still LOOKING for a simple workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Included data file should contain:

```
<?php
return array(
       array(
             data => 'infohere_01',
            )
       );
```

Comment: Thanks - will try this out and provide feed forward on the result.I was close, but not close enough to get it to work :-(

Comment: FEEDBACK::
Sorry but this solution does not work, as pointed out previously include does not work inside an array... what you get is::
    syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /home/ja

Comment: NOTE:: the use of ); rather than ), which was the MISTAKE that made this array not work - hence why I was getting the /data return??

Here is the correct 2d version code::

    <?php
          return array(
           array(
                 data => 'infohere_01',
                )
              );
    ?>

Comment: Will there be the accepted answer if the question is completely solved ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can have some variable declaration inside each of your include '/datafile_01.php':

```
<?php
    $foo = array(
       array(
             data => 'infohere_01',
            )
          ),
?>
```

Then you would be able to merge all your include files with something like this, and thus building your big array:

```
<?php
  $dataFile = array();

  foreach($includeFiles as $file)
  {
    include($file);
    $dataFile[] = $foo;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - will try this out and provide feed forward on the result.

Comment: Just attempted to use your example...
$foo is where?
$includefiles is coming from where?
$x ?? 

tried it several ways - no result except I did get /data as a result.

Still LOOKING for HELP

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the answer, $x should be $foo.

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorted it now using KISS
Keeping it stupid simple!

Breaking it down into the basics, you find a solution - the complexity of 3d arrays, causing complexity itself, but with additional errors between 2d/3d coding using ), and/or ); there was a compounding of errors going on.

The 2 comments made, both gave a indication towards solving the problem, using RETURN and a loop to include the includes, but the real gem came from further research.
I quote:

> Thanks for your help everyone. I found the answer, and I feel pretty
>   silly: Adding to 3D arrays is as easy as adding to regular arrays!
>
> $users[] = $newuser;
>
> That's bloody it! Amazing, huh? If $users is a 3D array, and $newuser
>   is an array, it just adds it to the 3D array like I need it to. When
>   all else fails, try the simplest thing you can think of! Oh well, the
>   5-6 hours I spent researching this
>
> answered some questions I'll need to take care of later, and I
>   learned a ton while at it.
>
> **Source:** [http://www.v7n.com/forums/coding-forum/49651-php-appending-multidimensional-arrays.html][1]

OK so what have I created::

Simple 2D arrays for each file
that is then created by adding to a 3d array as follows!

```
 $shop = array();

    $shop[] = include 'Catalogue_ARRAYS/Fire-and-Rescue-Tools_2009.php';
    $shop[] = include 'Catalogue_ARRAYS/Insulated-Digging-Tools_2013.php';
```

**Simple really** - typical KISS

The 2d arrays / Include.php files are constructed as follows, using **RETURN** array( rather than $foo = array(::
NOTE:: the use of **);** rather than **),** which was the MISTAKE!

```
<?php
    return array(
           array(
             data => 'infohere_01',
           )
         **);**
?>
```

**That's it SOLVED!**

Thanks to all of you who have contributed. We where nearly alright, but sods-law a mini mistake here and there with ' and ; kills things dead.

Thanks again